# Unexpected token ILLEGAL with dangerouslySetInnerHTML

Tags: symfony, reactjs, twig

I am using Symfony2 framework with reactjs for view part. I have a twig variable having html tags.
So I did this -  `<span {{"dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: ' "~content|raw~" '}}"}}></span>`

But this is giving me following error

```
Error: Parse Error: Line 95: Unexpected token ILLEGAL
at http://localhost/url/abcd 
... ouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: &#039;&lt;p&gt;&lt;/p&gt;&lt;p&g ...
```

When I write something like `<span {{"dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: '<div>abcd</div>'}}"}}></span>` , Then everything works fine. But when I use a twig variable, this error is thrown.

Comment: i probably don't understand the problem but may the verbatim tagmark can help you http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/verbatim.html   Can you replicate the problem in a  twigfiddle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend using twig only to output your delimiters and the variable itself:

```
<span dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ '{{' }}__html: '{{ content|raw }}' {{ '}}' }}></span>
```

Comment: Its still giving an error Error: Parse Error: Line 95: Unexpected identifier
    at http://localhost/url/abcd

... html: '<p></p><p>Perhaps you've heard of this phrase "m ...
                                ^

Comment: The above error mentioned in comment was due to a single quote in my string. I replaced single quotes with &#039;
Your Answer is perfect